# WPF SizeChanged event doesn't fire

Tags: c#, wpf

This is a bit of a noob question.

Basically, I have a grid `MainGrid`in my WPF window

I'd simply like to be notified when the  `MainGrid`is resized ( when user maximizes/resizes the window).

This does nothing at the moment. Am I supposed to declare and then add this SizeChanged event earlier before it will work?

```
private void MainGrid_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyTextBox.Text = "MainGrid resized";
        }
```

Thank you

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhh :) Yes it worked! I feel like fred flintstone .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have your event in code-behind and this in XAML:

```
<Grid SizeChanged="MainGrid_SizeChanged">
```

it will work.